# Multiple-line example in openapi v3 response body

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Is there a way to code a multiple-line example in a request body? If possible I'd like my OpenApi document to display as follows when running under Swagger-UI.

[image: Desired result]

So far, all I've been able to achieve is a single-line example, as seen below:

[image: Single line example]

Answer (score 0):

You don't say much about your language of choice for your api or how you are generating your swagger.json ...

But yes it is possible, Here are some live examples:

http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Company#/Company/Company_Post

http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Polygon#/PolygonVolume/PolygonVolume_Post

http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Dictionary#/Dictionary/Dictionary_DeleteEcho

the json code for that last one looks like this :

```
"delete": {
    "tags": [
      "Dictionary"
    ],
    "operationId": "Dictionary_DeleteEcho",
    "consumes": [
      "application/json",
      "text/json",
      "text/html"
    ],
    "produces": [
      "application/json",
      "text/json",
      "text/html"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "guids",
        "in": "body",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "format": "uuid",
            "type": "string",
            "example": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
          },
          "example": [
            "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
...
```